# For all integers $n$, $ n^2 + n + 1$ is odd

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-verification

Can someone verify my proof of the statement in the title?

Suppose that $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

If $n$ is odd, say $n = 5$, then $n^2 + n + 1 = 31$ which is also
odd.

If $n$ is even, say $n = 4$, then $n^2 + n + 1 = 21$ which is odd.

Hence for all integers $n$, $n^2 + n + 1$ is odd.

Comment: What is the set?

Comment: Integers - thank you.

Comment: Also this is not a valid proof. You cannot take a particular $n$. Instead, your reasoning has to be based on _all_ $n$.

Comment: Hint: the product of two consecutive numbers must be even, so $n(n+1)$ is even, so $n(n+1) + 1$ is odd.

Comment: I don't understand all these downvotes without comment? Do you blame the OP of not knowing how to write a correct proof?

Answer (score 3):

Observe that $(n^2 + n +1) - 1 = n(n+1)$ is the product of two consecutive integers, hence even. Thus $n^2 + n + 1$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. $n^2$ is odd/even iff $n$ is odd/even
2. $n+1$ is odd/even iff $n$ is even/odd
3. The sum of two numbers is even iff they have the same parity

Another way is to look first at even numbers, i.e. of the form $2k$. And the at odd numbers, i.e. numbers of the form $2k+1$. As these cover all cases, proving your statement for these families delivers the full proof.

Answer (score 1):

The general argument can go as follows.  If $n$ is odd, then so is $n^2$.  If $n$ is even, then so is $n^2$.  Consequently, $n^2 + n$ is the sum of two numbers of the same parity, hence is always even.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=2k$ we have $n^2+n+1=2(2k^2+k)+1\in\mathrm {Odd}.$
For $n=2k+1$ we have $n^2+n+1 = 2(2k^2+3k+1)+1\in\mathrm {Odd}.$
Proved.

Comment: I think this is the proof with most value for the OP. The OP's experience  of proofs and logic seems to be rather small. So I think it does not make sense to try to write very  elegant or short proofs, but it is necessary to write a precise, complete proof that uses the definition of odd and even.

Comment: I agree that formula express the essence better than words

Answer (score 0):

$$n^2+n+1 = (n+1)^2-n$$

$(n+1)^2$ is odd if and only if $n+1$ is odd; i.e. if and only if $n$ is even.

So this is either $\text{even}-\text{odd}$ or $\text{odd}-\text{even}$, which is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following cases:

- $n\equiv\color\red0\pmod2 \implies n^2+n+1\equiv\color\red0^2+\color\red0+1\equiv1\pmod2$
- $n\equiv\color\red1\pmod2 \implies n^2+n+1\equiv\color\red1^2+\color\red1+1\equiv3\equiv1\pmod2$